# Apply opacity to gradient colors in flutter

Tags: flutter

For colors we can use `Color.withOpacity` but this method does not exist for gradients.
Whats the easiest method to apply opacity to each color on an existing gradient?
Is this even possible?

Ive tried to implement a custom extension for `Gradient` but this idea does not seem to work because I dont know what gradient it is so currently I have to implement extensions for each type of gradient.

```dart
extension LinearGradientExtension on LinearGradient {
  
  /// Applies [opacity] to all colors in gradient and returns a new [LinearGradient]
  LinearGradient withOpacity(double opacity) {
    return LinearGradient(
      colors: _applyOpacity(colors, opacity),
      begin: begin,
      end: end,
      stops: stops,
      tileMode: tileMode,
      transform: transform,
    );
  }
}

extension RadialGradientExtension on RadialGradient {

  /// Applies [opacity] to all colors in gradient and returns a new [RadialGradient]
  RadialGradient withOpacity(double opacity) {
    /// ...
  }

}


List<Color> _applyOpacity(List<Color> colors, double opacity) {
  return colors
    .map((Color color) => color.withOpacity(color.opacity * opacity))
    .toList()
  ;
}
```

I dont want to use any widgets (like `Opacity`) for this.

Answer (score 5):

The color parameter requires a List of Color, so you can basically place any color widget with any opacity in that list.

For linear gradients I used this implementation, hope this is what you are looking for

```
        Container(
          foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
              ],
            ),
          )
```